# mySQL joining multiple tables together

Tags: mysql, join, export-to-csv

I have about 10 tables, all with varying number of columns but all contain the column 'client_id' which is the key to link all the records in each table together.

I want to grab all columns in all tables.

what would be the best way to join all 10 or so tables together on the client_id?

The reason for wanting to do this is because I want to export all tables in 1 single CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

Start with a table that contains all the client ids and left join the remaining tables with the `USING` keyword:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM table1
 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (client_id)
 LEFT JOIN table3 USING (client_id)
 LEFT JOIN table4 USING (client_id)
 ...
```

Comment: thanks, it works but I seem to be getting duplicate values? the number in duplicates seem to be increasing from the more tables i join on. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1859127: I guess the thing you are doing wrong is assuming that it's a sensible idea to fetch all your data and save it in a single CSV file. You should probably use one CSV file per table.

Comment: the reason for doing so is because i have a 3rd party tool that allows for data insertion via csv. So importing 1 csv file at a time would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1 t1,
table2 t2,
table3 t3...
where t1.user_id=t2.user_id
and t1.user_id=t3.user_id...
```